# Array Multidimensional PHP foreach

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de Saber como fazer uma pesquisa de modelo de um carro usando o foreach, dada a tabela abaixo:

```
 /*
Carro                       modelo                      ano

toyota          "corrola","allion","Ranx","mark"        2008        
Mazda           "Atenza","Demio","MPV"                  2000

*/
```

Comment: Tem como colocar como essa tabela está estruturada no PHP? O carro é o índice?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que assim fica mais fácil de dar manutenção:

```
<?php
$carros["toyota"]["modelos"] = array("corrola","allion","Ranx","mark");
$carros["Mazda"]["modelos"] = array("Atenza","Demio","MPV");

$carros["toyota"]["ano"] = 2008;
$carros["Mazda"]["ano"] = 2008;

foreach($carros as $carro) {
    foreach($carro["modelos"] as $modelo) {
        if($modelo == "Demio"){
            echo "Modelo " . $modelo . " Encontrado";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```